# Trying to get .Net Boxed Framework to work Using .Net Core Framework 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, graphql

I have been asked to configure and figure out how to get the .NET boxed framework to work using .NET framework 3.0. I am stuck on how to fix this issue as I have never seen it before and don't quiet understand how to get it to work.

If anyone has an idea or has gotten this frame work working in 3.0 help would be much appreciated.

I have mainly been looking up other ways to use the `IServiceProvider` but the only sort of solution I have come up with is that I have to get all there services into a variable and inject it that way according to the error message anyway

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) =>
            services
                .AddCorrelationIdFluent()
                .AddCustomCaching()
                .AddCustomOptions(this.configuration)
                .AddCustomRouting()
                .AddCustomResponseCompression()
                .AddCustomStrictTransportSecurity()
                .AddCustomHealthChecks()
                .AddHttpContextAccessor()
                .AddMvcCore()
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                    .AddAuthorization()
                    .AddJsonFormatters()
                    .AddCustomJsonOptions(this.hostingEnvironment)
                    .AddCustomCors()
                    .AddCustomMvcOptions(this.hostingEnvironment)
                .Services
                .AddCustomGraphQL(this.hostingEnvironment)
                .AddCustomGraphQLAuthorization()
                .AddProjectRepositories()
                .AddProjectSchemas()
                .BuildServiceProvider();
```

This is what the error message says:

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'

**Note:** I have not added any extra code into the framework yet just trying to make it error free for version 3.0.

If anyone has any ideas help would much appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/Dotnet-Boxed/Framework ?

Comment: Yes but this one specifically https://github.com/Dotnet-Boxed/Templates/blob/master/Docs/GraphQL.md I don't know if there is a difference though. There was no tag to use for this framework so I had to leave it out

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is 100% correct because I have no way of testing it right now but here is what I did to get this code section above error free.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            _ = services
               .AddCorrelationIdFluent()
               .AddCustomCaching()
               .AddCustomOptions(this.configuration)
               .AddCustomRouting()
               .AddCustomResponseCompression()
               .AddCustomStrictTransportSecurity()
               .AddCustomHealthChecks()
               .AddHttpContextAccessor()
               .AddMvcCore()
                   .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                   .AddAuthorization()
                   .AddCustomJsonOptions(this.hostingEnvironment)
                   .AddCustomCors()
                   .AddCustomMvcOptions(this.hostingEnvironment);

            _ = services
               .AddCustomGraphQL(this.hostingEnvironment)
               .AddCustomGraphQLAuthorization()
               .AddProjectRepositories()
               .AddProjectSchemas();

            _ = services.AddMvc()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }
```

I was told by a co-worker to take out the `.BuildServiceProvider` so that is why it is no longer there If this is wrong or anyone know a better way let us know :)